# Почему не наследуется конструктор?

Tags: javascript

Есть **2** функции конструкторов, прототип **1-ой** функции-конструктора наследуется через `Object.create`, но в качестве прототипа ошибочно указан не объект(прототип), а сама функция конструктор. Т.е это ошибка при наследовании прототипа. Но почему из-за этого не работает наследование конструктора во **2** функции-конструктора ?

Пример кода:

```js
function Name(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Name.prototype.sayName = function() {
  console.log(this.name)
}

function FullName(name, surname) {
  Name.call(this, name); //2 - but why didn't work this ?
  this.surname = surname;
}

FullName.prototype = Object.create(Name); //1 - mistake

FullName.prototype.sayFullName = function() {
  console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.surname);
}

var person = new FullName('Boris', 'Akunin');

console.log('person', person)
```

В объекте `person` будет только свойство surname. В строке **1** была допущена ошибка, но она же, вроде, никак не влияет на наследование конструктора. Т.е в строке **2** идет обычный вызов функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как ни странно, именно ошибка в строке `(1)` сломала вызов родительского конструктора. :)

Тонкость тут в том, что экземпляры класса `Function` (т. е. все функции, включая конструкторы) имеют свойство `name`, причём оно неперезаписываемое:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(function(){}, 'name')
/* возвращает 
   {value: "", writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
 */
```

А неперезаписываемое свойство при наследование блокирует своё изменение даже на объектах-потомках, подробнее об этом можно прочитать на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Inheritance_of_properties).

Таким образом, экземпляр класса `FullName` наследуется от экземпляра класса Function, который уже имеет неперезаписываемое `name` и конструктор `Name` изменить его не может.

Есть два решения — исправить уже указанную ошибку:

```
FullName.prototype = Object.create(Name.prototype);
```

либо просто переименовать свойство `name`. :)